# Finitely presented group with intermediate Turing degree word problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computability, combinatorial-group-theory

Does there exist a finitely presented group with undecidable word problem, but so that an oracle to solve the word problem for this group wouldn't be sufficient to solve the halting problem in general?

I'd imagine there's no known example, as there aren't "natural" problems we know of that are undecidable but less hard than the halting problem, although maybe there is some argument against that possibility here, or at least a reason we should expect things to go one way or another.

Comment: Have you thought about the WP for semigroups or rewriting systems? These are closer to Turing machines, so you might have more luck there, and then can try to extend what you learn to the group case. (Although the paper of Birget, Rips, Ol'Shanskii and Sapi I cite in the comment below essentially "embeds" a given Turing machine into a group, so might be promising. But the paper is *hard*, if I recall correctly!)

Comment: You might also want to check https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01862896v2/document , where it is proved that for any Turing degree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree, that's your notion of oracle in a nutshell) there exists a subgroup (of a natural enough family of groups) with Word Problem of that degree. This paper however does require some solid knowledge in symbolic dynamics though.
Regarding more natural classes, you might also have a look at http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~lc45/Conferences/2010/diablerets.pdf (in the decidable world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might not be specific known examples, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups gives an example of a mapping from a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ to a group $G: \langle a,b,c,d| a^nba^n=c^ndc^n , n\in A\rangle$ with presumably the same complexity for its word problem. This group isn't FP, but there's also mention in that article that every FG group with recursively enumerable presentation is a subgroup of a FP group with insoluble word problem; I would suggest checking the references to see if that construction maintains complexity, since that would give your answer.

Comment: The construction is simply Higman's embedding theorem. There *are* results about the complexity of the WP in these embeddings, but they seem to be more positive, e.g. the paper *Isoperimetric functions of groups and computational complexity of the word problem* by Birget, Rips, Ol'Shanskii and Sapir ([doi](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3597196)) (Higman's theorem says that every RP groups embeds into a FP group; as the WP is preserved under taking subgroups the result you state follows immediately -- proving decidability is preserved is less obvious, and so presumably studied more?)

Answer (score 0):

Having a decidable word problem for a recursively presented group is a $\Sigma^0_3$ (complete) property, whereas the Halting set is $\Sigma^0_1$ complete, so necessarily any oracle that decides on the first will decide on the Halting problem, I am pretty sure.